# FollowHyperlink in Access issue

Tags: google-chrome, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

My database is used for ecommerce holding data for Creating and updating products online to the likes of Wal Mart and Amazon etc.

I've been working to make the daily work of maintaining listings easier and have added hyperlink buttons that go directly to the listing page on Amazon or Wal Mart etc.  Works like a charm.

Recently I created links to go directly to the edit pages for our products, making changes quicker for the staff. Yes, indeed, works like a charm for Wal Mart, not so much for Amazon.  I'm fairly certain login credentials are the issue but I've no idea how to go about making this work.

The hyperlink:
https://vendorcentral.amazon.com/hz/vendor/members/products/images/manage?products=B073GPZQDS-CYCS4

It works perfectly when copied and pasted into Chrome.  When the FollowHyperlink is used on a button it does not.

I realize you fine folks can't test the link as it requires login info I can't give out.  But, can you tell me what might be firing differently with using Followhyperlink as opposed to a copy/paste into browser?  Why one would work and the other wouldn't?

The code is simple:

```
Private Sub Command20_Click()
    FollowHyperlink Me.StoreEditLink
End Sub
```

As an example the Wal Mart link works fine on a button using FollowHyperlink:

https://supplier.walmart.com/editItem/0698238533928?idType=GTIN&readonly=false&isSetup=false&product_id=4R00WBYFZBVN

Thanks!

Comment: Cookies are why it works in the browser and not in Access. You've likely logged in already in the browser - copy/pasting just uses your logged in status in cookies to bypass the login requirements

Comment: Thank you, that's totally understandable.  But, the Wal Mart link also requires login credentials and does work.  So cookies doesn't entirely explain the difference between the two.  

FTR I'm already logged into both sites prior to executing the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try opening the page using Shell Function?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/shell-function

```
shell("C:\Users\**USERNAME**\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://vendorcentral.amazon.com/hz/vendor/members/products/images/manage?products=B073GPZQDS-CYCS4")
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works like a charm.  I was so narrowly focused on hyperlinks, and solving why one worked and the other didn't, a shell wasn't even on my radar.  Which is why I love this site!

I did have to change the path as this is running on (I know... not my fault) Windows 7.

Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://vendorcentral.amazon.com/hz/vendor/members/products/images/manage?products=B073GPZQDS-CYCS4")

Thank you Mihai!

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)